# discord.js v12 permissions

Tags: permissions, discord, discord.js

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eygew.png)

I need this code to work only for two person. If the command is used by someone else, then **return** is issued. But in my case, **return** is always issued. Why?

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DglY.png)

```html
{
 if(message.author.id != "347030464462192651" || message.author.id != "586526295366565889") {
 return message.channel.send(`This command can only be used by the <@&791356969091989555>`)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well you have this code:

```
if(message.author.id != "347030464462192651" || message.author.id != "586526295366565889") {
 return message.channel.send(`This command can only be used by the <@&791356969091989555>`)
}
```

And you know there's a problem with it. So look at your code closer, and figure out what it's actually doing. Or debug it, using a debugger would easily show you why this is occurring. It's a simple logical error that you could solve in seconds by changing up parts of the `if` statement or simply thinking through what your `if` statement is currently doing. Please try to learn more about javascript and do more research before asking questions like this on StackOverflow.

**The Problem**

So let's work through what your code is currently doing. Let's start by "translating" your code into English, essentially turning it back into pseudo-code:

- Take the message author's ID

  - If the ID is not `347030464462192651`, return
  - OR
  - If the ID is not `586526295366565889`, return

Now let's use the ID `586526295366565889` and see what this code does when we use this ID.

- Take the message author's ID: `586526295366565889`

  - If the ID is not `347030464462192651`, return

    - `586526295366565889` is not `347030464462192651`, so we should return

Now let's use the other ID (`347030464462192651`) and see what this code does when we use that ID.

- Take the message author's ID: `347030464462192651`

  - If the ID is not `347030464462192651`, return

    - The ID is `347030464462192651`, so continue to the below check
  - OR
  - If the ID is not `586526295366565889`, return

    - `347030464462192651` is not `586526295366565889`, so we should return

Do you see what's happening here? You're using `||` which is a logical `OR` operator. So if *either* of the checks in the `if` statement (`(message.author.id != "347030464462192651"` and `message.author.id != "586526295366565889"`) is true, then the code will return. So you see, when the ID is not equal to even one of those two specified IDs, it will return true (and obviously if you have one of those two IDs, it will not be equal to the other ID).

Whereas `OR` (`||`) would return when *either* of the checks are true, `AND` (`&&`) would only return when *both* of the checks are true. That changes your logic to:

- Take the message author's ID

  - If the ID is not `347030464462192651`, return
  - AND
  - If the ID is not `586526295366565889`, return

That's just one possible solution though. There are many different logical combinations that yield the same result; two that I can think of at the moment, including the above solution: `id != x && id != y`, `!(id == x || id == y)`.

**The Solutions (Please Read Problem First)**

So here's those two possible solutions below. You can implement either one. **But please don't just copy and paste these solutions.** Read the above explanation, understand what the logic is doing, and make sure you understand the solution. If you don't, you will simply make the exact same mistake in the future; and if you were to then ask for help on the same problem on StackOverflow again, it would waste our time on an immensely simple solution that you should already have grasped after this question.

Logical AND (with !=):

```
if(message.author.id != "347030464462192651" && message.author.id != "586526295366565889") {
 return message.channel.send(`This command can only be used by the <@&791356969091989555>`)
}
```

Logical NOT OR (with ==):

```
if(!(message.author.id == "347030464462192651" || message.author.id == "586526295366565889")) {
 return message.channel.send(`This command can only be used by the <@&791356969091989555>`)
}
```

These two solutions are actually the same solution, written in two different ways. If you were to "distribute" the NOT in the second solution (similar to how you might in a simple algebraic problem), all of the `==` would become `!=` and the `||` would become `&&` (which is the first solution)!

Hopefully you understood what is wrong with your code, and I hope you thoroughly read and understood the problem as I described it above. Look at the process I used to solve your problem in the **The Problem** section, and try to use that process yourself in the future; you'll find that it will make it much easier to solve virtually any logical problem you stumble into.